# Sent Email via Python using Mailgun API

Tags: python, email, mailgun

I try to send email via python using Mailgun

I have

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox6247218655a94010b9840c23c2688fc7.mailgun.org",
        auth=("api", "key-********"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <bb@gmail.com>",
              "to": ["bb@outlook.com", "bb4@gmail.com"],
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

I realize I forgot `/messages`

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox6247218655a94010b9840c23c2688fc7.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "key-********"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <bb@gmail.com>",
              "to": ["bb@outlook.com", "bb4@gmail.com"],
              "subject": "Hello",
              "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

I run it

```
python mail.py
```

I still don't see any email. 
I also check my MailGun and my spam folder.

Any hints for me ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [MailGun documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-via-api), here you can see that the POST url should be in this format `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages`

From your piece of code, I can see that `sandbox6247218655a94010b9840c23c2688fc7.mailgun.org` is `YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME` but your missing the format which is the `/messages` API endpoint.

So all you have to do is to add the `/messages` endpoint to your post URL. So it changes from `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox6247218655a94010b9840c23c2688fc7.mailgun.org` to `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox6247218655a94010b9840c23c2688fc7.mailgun.org/messages`.

Comment: After update that I still see 0 message in my mail box !

Answer (score 1):

Also note that if your domain is added to the EU region (instead of US) you have to change the post URL domain from `api.mailgun.net` to `api.eu.mailgun.net` (note the `.eu`), as read in the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/quickstart-sending.html#send-with-smtp-or-api).

So the entire URL would be `https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should change the email in "from" field to match the domain you registered on Mailgun. At least It seems so from [Mailgun documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#examples), where the placeholder text for the "from" email is `YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME`

The code should be:

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
    "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox6247218655a94010b9840c23c2688fc7.mailgun.org/messages",
    auth=("api", "key-********"),
    data={"from": "Excited User <bb@sandbox6247218655a94010b9840c23c2688fc7.mailgun.org>",
          "to": ["bb@outlook.com", "bb4@gmail.com"],
          "subject": "Hello",
          "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

Also, make sure that in your script you call the function you are defining :-)